# How to add Attribute and use after building the model?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I’ve built a neural network model and I’d like to incorporate custom functions, encodeImage and encodeText , for pre-processing data. Ideally, I want these functions to be callable both during model definition and after training (post-build). However, including them directly within the model definition restricts their use to before Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation. Calls made after model building result in the functions being undefined

```
# The Custom Attributes I wan to add in the Model
    def encode_image(self, image):
      return self.visual(image.type(self.dtype))

    def encode_text(self, text):
      x = self.token_embedding(text).type(self.dtype)  # [batch_size, n_ctx, d_model]

      x = x + self.positional_embedding.type(self.dtype)
      x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)  # NLD -> LND
      x = self.transformer(x)
      x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)  # LND -> NLD
      x = self.ln_final(x).type(self.dtype)

      # x.shape = [batch_size, n_ctx, transformer.width]
      # take features from the eot embedding (eot_token is the highest number in each sequence)
      x = x[torch.arange(x.shape[0]), text.argmax(dim=-1)] @ self.text_projection

      return x
  # Image Classifier Neural Network
  class ImageClassifier(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self, n_qubits, n_layers, encode_image):
          super().__init__()
          self.model = nn.Sequential(
              qlayer,
              ClassicalLayer(2)
          )
  
      def forward(self, x):
          result = self.model(x)
          return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your scripted function to contain only model operations - ie no preprocessing, i/o, device transfer, etc.

Dataloading/preprocessing logic should be separate from model logic. For example, tokenization should not occur within the model code.

Once logic is separated, additional functions can be added by implementing them in the `module` class and adding the `@torch.jit.export`. By default, torch scripting will compile the `forward` method and any other methods that include the `@torch.jit.export` decorator. See this example from the pytorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#torch.jit.export)

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def implicitly_compiled_method(self, x):
        return x + 99

    # `forward` is implicitly decorated with `@torch.jit.export`,
    # so adding it here would have no effect
    def forward(self, x):
        return x + 10

    @torch.jit.export
    def another_forward(self, x):
        # When the compiler sees this call, it will compile
        # `implicitly_compiled_method`
        return self.implicitly_compiled_method(x)

    def unused_method(self, x):
        return x - 20

# `m` will contain compiled methods:
#     `forward`
#     `another_forward`
#     `implicitly_compiled_method`
# `unused_method` will not be compiled since it was not called from
# any compiled methods and wasn't decorated with `@torch.jit.export`
m = torch.jit.script(MyModule())
```